# How do I write a sinatra API to receive a POST from AngularJS $http

Tags: ruby, json, angularjs, post, sinatra

```
      $http({
       method: "POST",
       url: "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/angular",
       data: {message: $scope.newChat}
      })
```

I thought that if I enable it to receive JSON, it would be fine, but I still get a 404 error with an OPTIONS method:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/json'
require 'json'

post '/angular' do

 data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
 json data

end
```

But it's not working.  What do I need to change on either/both the angularJS side and my sinatra server side in order to accept posts and send a response back to the client?

Comment: Is ajax located on the same domain? Cross-domain ajax requests are forbidden due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on the assumption that this is a cross origin request.  If this is the case CORS is disabled by default due to security reasons; as it should be.

You will need to enable CORS; in Sinatra I typically use the sinatra-cross_origin extension for this.

[sinatra-cross_origin](https://github.com/britg/sinatra-cross_origin)

To enable CORS for the entire service you would use something like follows.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cross_origin'

configure do
  enable :cross_origin
end
```

To enable for only specific routes it would look more like follows.

```
get '/cross_origin' do
  cross_origin
  "This is available to cross-origin javascripts"
end
```

Make sure you realize that this opens a big security risk and you are mitigating that risk appropriately.

The following for example will allow any origin to connect, which in the case of an open web service may be what you need.

```
set :allow_origin, :any
```

On the other hand you could limit it if possible

```
set :allow_origin, 'http://example.com'
```

If you need to open it up as a full web service to any origin then you will want to consider additional security measures such as TLS and OAuth, but that is a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing!  I think you may have solved it....i definitely want to be able to limit the origin that is allowed (basically my localhost for testing and the actual web-site.